# How to view Borderlands FPS without third party software

Tags: steam, borderlands-2, linux, framerate

I would like to see what my framerate is for Borderlands 2 (steam). However, the only way to do this that I can find on Google, is to install 3rd-party-software (fraps, EVGA monitor...). Right now, I am running Ubuntu, which is incompatible with all of these. Is there any way to see the framerate without installing anything?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Steam actually has a built in setting for you to check the FPS of any game. Go into setting and select the `In-Game` options and change the `In-Game FPS counter` to whatever position you want. This will then show some small text in one of the corners with the current FPS of the game.

[image: FPS Setting]

Comment: Thanks! This ended up being a lot simpler then I had imagined.